# Parse complexe xml in spark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Extract Xml data from TSV/CSV file in databricks

I need little help on xml data which coming in between Tsv file. Saw answer on few Databricks question forum . I am not sure if any UDF type function can be implemented and use directly. Requesting your input if anything can done in pyspark or any inbuilt databricks utility can handle it.

Need the tsv id,status other column along with few inner attribute from XML.
Please suggest how to implement the logic in pyspark or spark sql. Here file is not XML ,with in file one column have XML data.

I tried to read the file like text and convert it into dataframe . I need suggestion to extract the XML content from a dataframe.

File sample as shown below with header on top :

```
Id || UserId || UserSgid || ClientId || Version || WTVersion || Details || Status || DCT || DMD || Visible   


33144   
6587a872-23ce-4453-8c68-1209ac21352b    
ce9c6fcc-d20e-4f5f-8e64-e307849d1fda    
986b5314-7269-4bd3-abee-6f9b1b27b990    
1    
1   

<Workflow xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SMT.WorkflowSteps" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><DateCompleted i:nil="true" />

<DateStarted>2017-05-19T02:50:25.647</DateStarted>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Id>986b5314-7269-4bd3-abee-6f9b1b27b990</Id>
<Status>Started</Status>
<Visible>true</Visible>
<DateCreated>2019-08-22T21:47:24.8648778Z</DateCreated>
<ExecutionId>c2ea7b9d-cd6a-432f-8fd4-2e8cfae679e9</ExecutionId>
<Steps xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:anyType i:type="WorkflowPhase">
        <DateCompleted i:nil="true" />
        <DateStarted i:nil="true" />
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Id>8184775f-a5f2-4648-bb6b-cbc840f73a10</Id>
        <Status>NotStarted</Status>
        <Visible>true</Visible>
<Steps>
<a:anyType i:type="OldAccommodationRequestWorkflowStep">
    <DateCompleted i:nil="true" />
    <DateStarted i:nil="true">

1   
2016-05-18 17:19:37.9770000 
2019-08-22 21:47:36.3600000 
True
```

Need to extract data along with `Id,UserId,UserSgid,ClientId,Version,WTVersion` and few other data like `ExecutionId ,Status` etc from the column Details which has xml content.

Comment: Could you please explicit your file sample ? I can't make the difference between the Id and the xml part for example. Thanks

Comment: Hi Driss,Please find the sample file like below,

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=EVq6z3

Answer (score 1):

You can use the deprecated `xmlRdd` (which is the only solution, I can see now).
Suppose you have the following xml:

```
 public static void readFromString() {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Print Elements of RDD")
            .setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","2g");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    String books = "<persons>\n" +
            "    <person id=\"1\">\n" +
            "        <firstname>James</firstname>\n" +
            "        <lastname>Smith</lastname>\n" +
            "        <middlename></middlename>\n" +
            "        <dob_year>1980</dob_year>\n" +
            "        <dob_month>1</dob_month>\n" +
            "        <gender>M</gender>\n" +
            "        <salary currency=\"Euro\">10000</salary>\n" +
            "    </person>\n" +
            "</persons>";

    List<String> booksList = Arrays.asList(books);

    RDD<String> booksRDD = sc.parallelize(booksList, 1).rdd();

    Dataset<Row> rowDataset = new XmlReader().withRowTag("person").xmlRdd(new SQLContext(sc), booksRDD);

    rowDataset.printSchema();

    rowDataset.select("person.*").show();

}
```

Result of `rowDataset.printSchema()`:

```
root
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dob_month: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dob_year: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- salary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _currency: string (nullable = true)
```

Result of `rowDataset.select("person.*").show();`

```
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
|_id|dob_month|dob_year|firstname|gender|lastname|middlename|      salary|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1|        1|    1980|    James|     M|   Smith|          |[10000,Euro]|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
```

You can apply the same logic to your use case

Comment: Thanks Nejjar, Looking anything using dataframe, pyspark.. please suggest .. will see if this help as not looking to use RDD.

Comment: You can convert your RDD to a dataframe using `rdd.toDF` where rdd is your base rdd.

Comment: Thanks Nejjar, anything on pyspark or sparksql if you could suggest will great help